# Передача аргумента в функцию по дескриптору C++/CLR

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, clr

Есть 2 программы на C++/CLR:

1)

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

String^ InsertSpacesBeforBigLetters(String ^str)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < str->Length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            str = str->Insert(i, " ");
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return str;
}

int main()
{
    Console::WriteLine("Enter string:");
    String ^input_str = Console::ReadLine();

    //input_str = InsertSpacesBeforBigLetters(input_str);

    InsertSpacesBeforBigLetters(input_str);

    Console::WriteLine(input_str);

    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Программа, которая вставляем пробелы перед каждым большим символом строки, начиная с 1 (используется .NET класс String). В этом примере при передаче аргумента по дескриптору, его значение после выполнения функции остаётся таким же, как и при вхождении в функцию - то есть при вызове функции и передаче ей строки по дескриптору в качестве аргумента она не меняется.

2)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

ref class SomeObj
{
    public:
        int num;

        SomeObj()
        {
            num = 0;
        }

        SomeObj(int Num)
        {
            num = Num;
        }

        void Meth()
        {
            cout << "I'm an object with number " << num;
        }
};

void Upgrade(SomeObj ^smo)
{
    smo->num = smo->num + 1;
}

int main()
{
    SomeObj ^so = gcnew SomeObj(1);

    so->Meth();

    Upgrade(so);

    cout << "\n";
    so->Meth();

    Console::ReadKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь же имеется написанный мною, в качестве примера, ссылочный класс SomeObj, который находится в аналогичной ситуации, как и строка в прошлом примере, но при его передаче по дескриптору в метод Upgrade его значение меняется.

Вопрос: почему так происходит? По идеи, в обоих случаях состояние объекта должно меняться, ведь в [официальной документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yk97tc08.aspx) сказанно, что дескриптор ведёт себя как указатель на объект. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: А что вы называете словом «дескриптор»?

Comment: @VladD в c++/cli так называют "крышку" (`^`)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Правда? Не слыхал :( А почему не «управляемая ссылка»?

Comment: @Tymur Вы и вправду не так поняли. Есть разница между подменой объекта, и изменениями внутри _того же самого_ объекта. И кстати в C++, на который вы ссылаетесь, всё точно так же.

Comment: @VladD *чтобы было больше путаницы*

Comment: В платформе .NET класс String, хоть и ссылочный, является [неизменяемым](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx#Immutability) (иммутабельным).

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем я, походу, понял в чём проблема. При вызове функции создаётся новый указатель, которому присваивается значение, находящееся в указателе, который мы передаём этой функции. Тамким образом во 2 примере мы изменяем значение num объекта, на который указывает so. В первом же примере значение не меняется по той причине, что мы меняем знаение не объекта, по адресу который мы передали в качестве аргумента в функцию, а мы меняем значение указателя, который располагается в функции. Решение этой проблемы - передача объекта в функцию по ссылке, например: String ^%str.